# First Child acting differently

Tags: javascript, jquery

If there is a Ul above P tag the nth-child acts differently. I don't get the first child in nth-child(1) instead i get it in nth-child(2). some how its considering  Firstchild as UL or getting hiddenon the other hand eq(0) is working properly. Can somebody explain me the reason why is this happening.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
</ul>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('p:nth-child(2)').css('background','#ccc');
$('p:eq(0)').css('color','red');
```

**[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3xXfW/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is the 2nd child of the parent

Try nth-of-type

```
$('p:nth-of-type(1)').css('background', '#ccc');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/k4z5T/)

Comment: but if i am writing p:nth-child then should mean nth-child of that tag isn't it